# Implementing multi languages with CSS and PHP

Tags: php, css, multilingual

I'm building a small site, that needs to support 2 languages for the same page.
Each language has different buttons on the page, the buttons are basically some images with text inside.
The positioning of the buttons is done using a CSS file, one for every language.
Question is how do I implement the changing of button for every image. I could put a php if statement, and use some other src if lang == English or something else if lang == Russian, Or could implement this with the css file (I could do this with a div and set it's background in the CSS)?
 What would you recommend?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create three CSS files:

- One for english buttons
- One for russian buttons
- One for the rest

This would basically work this way: You create your buttons with a fallback name, for example

```
<button id="button_ok">OK</button>
```

and define different background images in your english/russian CSS files:

(english.css)

```
#button_ok {
  background-image: url(images/buttons/eng/ok.gif);
}
```

and (russian.css)

```
#button_ok {
  background-image: url(images/buttons/rus/ok.gif);
}
```

All other elements that do not change when the language is chosen come in the third file:

```
p {
  font-size: 1em; /* whatever*/
}
```

The last step is to choose at the top of every page which file you want to load:

```
if ($_GET['lang'] == 'eng')
    $cssFile = 'english.css';
elseif ($_GET['lang'] == 'rus')
    $cssFile = 'russian.css';
```

and include the special and the general css file in your head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="general.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $cssFile; ?>" />
```

Comment: I don't want to use a <button> tag, I just need an image..., so what do i do?

Comment: if you just want to show the image without letting the user click on it, you can simply use a div element. So instead of `<button ...`, you simply use `<div ...`. You have to define width and height in the css classes then, but otherwise it works as described above

Comment: Yeah thats the solution I used in the end, thanks. But I think it's kind of wrong because it makes you have to set the width and the height (smells fishy to me)

Comment: From a strict point of view, it is the only right solution to set width and height (which is a style thing) in a css ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using CSS by setting the background and size of the button.

use   < button> tag, its better because you can use css like "button{}" without having to put a class on it. Just a remind that < button> has a type like the input and it is "submit" as default if I remember correctly.

Btw, always try to depend on CSS instead of PHP, because on a next manutenance you will be glad that you did it.

or, if you going to use PHP, try using a function instead of hardcoding, even if it is just for one button, we never know if we will use it later.

hope it helped,
Joe

Comment: Doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: lol? (I could do this with a div and set it's background in the CSS). He knows what to do, he is asking the best way to do it, with PHP or CSS and I gave him what I think is the best answer.